# Why does fseek use read() system call?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, libc

I'm trying to understand the glibc implementation of `fseek`. To do so, I downloaded the glibc source code and tried to understand its function execution order.

I found the `fseek` implementation in `libio/fseek.c`. Basically, it calls the function (or rather the macro) `_IO_fseek()` using the same parameters. This macro is implemented in `libio/iolibio.h`.

It is defined as `_IO_seekoff_unlocked (__fp, __offset, __whence, _IOS_INPUT|_IOS_OUTPUT)` (implemented in `libio/ioseekoff.c`). The next step in its execution is rather confusing for me:

`_IO_seekoff_unlocked` basically returns `_IO_SEEKOFF (fp, offset, dir, mode);`, which returns `_IO_seekoff_unlocked (fp, offset, dir, mode);`, which should create a call loop.

Also, when using `strace` on an example program (`seek.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("[Fseek] Executing fseek\n");
    FILE *f = fopen("./seek.c", "rb");

    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
}
```

it shows that `fseek` will call the `read` system call, even though I could not find it in the glibc implementation.

```
...
write(1, "[Fseek] Executing fseek\n", 24[Fseek] Executing fseek
) = 24
openat(AT_FDCWD, "./seek.c", O_RDONLY)  = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=146, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=146, ...}) = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "#include <stdio.h>\n\nint main(voi"..., 146) = 146
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

My goal is to understand how the read system call is used here. I have my own implementation of the `read` system call, which works well for other tests I wrote but will fail for some reason when it is called via `fseek`.

As an example, I use `fseek` in a function to get the size of a file:

```
long get_file_size(const char *name)
{
    FILE *temp_file = fopen(name, "rb");
    if (temp_file == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(temp_file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long sz =  ftell(temp_file);
    fclose(temp_file);
    return sz;
}
```

This function will return the correct size with the "normal" `read` implementation but will fail with mine. So, if anybody can tell me how I can understand the use of `read` within `fseek` (which I could not find in the source), I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: "This function will return the correct size", Hmmm, `ftell()` returns a `long`.  This code uses `unsigned long` and omits an error check.  Rather than change the type of return, returning a `long` makes more sense.

Comment: May be a read is performed in order to reset the input buffer after a seek?

Comment: `_IO_SEEKOFF` calls `__seekoff` from the jump table

Comment: Also, strictly speaking your `get_file_size()` does not return the size of the file. Per [**7.21.9.4 The ftell function**, paragraph 2 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2): "For a text stream, its file position indicator contains **unspecified information**, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; **the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read**."

Comment: I changed my get_size function from "unsigned long" to long. It didnt change anything (as expected as the test size is 46byte, so nowhere close to the maximum values). Read might be used to reset the buffer, but for this lseek() would me more suitable i guess (not sure about this one), and as far as I can tell, _IO_SEEKOFF returns "return _IO_SEEKOFF (fp, offset, dir, mode); " ( copied directly from the source file)

Comment: I would like to remove the part for the size function. That is not interesting, rather boring indeed. What is interesting is why there is a `read` in the `fseek` for text files.

Comment: For telling the size of the file you need to open it in binary mode. And you'll use `fstat` instead of seek and tell..

Comment: Actually I am going to change *that too* because it does not seem to matter.

Comment: here it is: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/wfileops.c.html#902 the read call

Comment: @KamilCuk answer please :D

Comment: @AndrewHenle i implemented an alternative get_size function using lseek, which gives the correct size. But my problem still exists I guess? If the current fet_size function does not work with my read() implementation, yet it does with the reference implementation, I have an error somewhere right? Or is it undefined behaviour of the current get_size, and thus cannot be fixed?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala *For telling the size of the file you need to open it in binary mode.* And that's pedantically [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268): "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream ..."  There's really no portable, strictly-conforming way to get the size of a file in C.  Using a binary stream relies on platform-specific guarantees, so you might as well use the platform's facilities that get the size directly, such as `stat()` or `GetFileSize()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle ah good point, I guess it is POSIX-defined though.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala POSIX does define `ftell()` to return an actual, accurate byte offset.

Comment: Anyway, the `get_size` function question is boring and can't be fixed, except by "use stat". The "why there is read in seek" is interesting. The read has nothing to do with your code failing, it is just b0rken.

Comment: @MajorasKid I don't see any actual errors, assuming a POSIX system - the interesting thing is why your code causes an underlying `read()` call.  Just don't return `0` on an error - otherwise you'll confuse empty files with non-existent files.

Comment: the cause for the read is this: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/wfileops.c.html#887  - I'd really wanna remove the get_file_size and just have that one.

Comment: oke thanks @AnttiHaapala. But yes, would still be interesting to see where the read() call comes from.

Comment: The function is correct on POSIX, but bad. There is just something totally wrong with your *read system call*, but that would be a separate question, for which you need to add the code for *that*. Hmm I will rephrase the question so that people do not get stuck...

Comment: Hm I'm sorry, but i cannot find how the execution of fseek() ends up in _IO_wfile_seekoff. Did i overlooked something in the function call order above?. I will write a new question for my read() implementation, as it would be too offtopic for this question i guess. Thanks for any help here anyways!

Answer (score 6):

[`_IO_seekoff_unlocked->_IO_SEEKOFF`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/2a764c6ee848dfe92cb2921ed3b14085f15d9e79/libio/ioseekoff.c#L59) actually expands to [`JUMP3 (__seekoff, FP, OFF, DIR, MODE)`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/libio/libioP.h#L188). [`JUMP3`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/libio/libioP.h#L121) is a macro that calls `__seekoff` from the `FILE` ["jump" table/vtable](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/libio/libioP.h#L300).

[fopen](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/a5406364ac949f91867352cb2ae867629f083c5b/libio/iofopen.c#L73) by default assigns [`_IO_file_jumps`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/a5406364ac949f91867352cb2ae867629f083c5b/libio/fileops.c#L1440) (or something like that, because the file can be mmap-ed etc. etc.) as the jump table for new `FILE`s. It is the implementation of the jump table/virtual table for a `FILE`.

So `_IO_SEEKOFF` calls [`_IO_file_jumps->__seekoff`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/fileops.c.html#1450). It points to [`_IO_new_file_seekoff`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/fileops.c.html#_IO_new_file_seekoff) and finally inside that function a call is made to [`_IO_SYSREAD`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/fileops.c.html#1023). [`_IO_SYSREAD`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/libioP.h.html#_M/_IO_SYSREAD) calls `_read` from the jump table, which in turn calls [`_IO_file_read`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/fileops.c.html#_IO_file_read), which calls [`__read`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c.html#30) which finally executes [`SYSCALL_CANCEL (read)`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c.html#30).

Comment: And the why part ;)

Comment: That's the hard part ; ) I actually am puzzled why doesn't it call `lseek` syscall.

Comment: @KamilCuk No kidding.  I suspect it has something to do with that "Puff..." comment you had in originally, and a GLIBC maintainer with waaaay too much free time.  The reasoning for such an "optimization" has to be, umm, interesting.  That's a LOT of O&M technical debt there.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I guess the cause is reasoning that lead to this comment: [`/* Try to seek to a block boundary, to improve kernel page management. */`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/wfileops.c.html#887)

Comment: Maybe buffering?